# Select data from table using data from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one is called companies (with columns: title, finance, address, phone....) and the other is called investments (with columns: title, budget....).

The `title` value is same in both tables example: google inc as title is stored in both tables.

All I want to do is display data from table "investments" to a page called companies-profile using title as key.

companies-profile page shows data based on id that I get from another page (where all companies are displayed).

I use this code:

```
<?php

    $var1 = "SELECT title 
            FROM companies 
            WHERE idcompanies='$ID'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT budget 
                                    FROM n4399 
                                    WHERE title='{$var1}'") 
                or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    $row2   = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    echo $row2['budget'];

?>
```

$conn is declared and database conection is ok

i m getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2'" at line 1

2 is the id that is selected by the user
Using xamp

Comment: Please provide your sql and I may be able to help

Comment: You haven't executed your first query...

Comment: @Nick its being used as a subquery :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly it needs to be enclosed in `()` and not `''` in that case...

Comment: @Nick YUP, Beat me to it

Comment: Also you dont appear to be setting `$ID` anywhere in the code, but I assume that because you are not showing all the code

Comment: i put () on it but it doesnt make any difference, first query executes fine if i execute it alone and displays the corect companie title. here is the ID set <?php
    $ID = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_GET['ID']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE idcompanies='$ID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single query

```
SELECT budget 
FROM companies 
INNER JOIN n4399 ON companies.Title=n4399.title
WHERE companies.id = ?
```

and  using a proper prepared  statement and binding

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT budget 
        FROM companies 
        INNER JOIN n4399 ON companies.Title=n4399.title
        WHERE companies.id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();

// 
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row['budget'];
}
```

Comment: If you are going to change things that much, you might like to show the code for  prepare and execute as well, otherwise the OP is probably going to be a little lost and ignore this answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute the following sql sentence:

```
SELECT budget 
  FROM n4399 
 WHERE title='SELECT title 
        FROM companies 
        WHERE idcompanies='$ID''
```

Either of two: or you first execute the firs sentence (select title from companies...) getting the effective title of the company or you can change your select into this:

```
SELECT budget 
  FROM n4399 
 WHERE title in (SELECT title 
        FROM companies 
        WHERE idcompanies='$ID')
```

So that this select can return all the values that have matching titles in the second select.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the $ID and put an exact value instead???

Comment: Putting the exact value stops page being filled automatically by taking data depending on ID that user has selected. I think the things i tried so far doesnt work cause i trying to read a string. I m trying to make it work by adding foreign key to my tables.

Comment: @ThLiou, I am not saying that you should put this exact value for good, the intent is to replace this $ID with an exact value and see what happens. If everything works (except that is returned the same value no matter what the user enters), then the problem is in the variable. If you are getting error despite the changes, then the error is somewhere else